# How to limit Beautiful soup find_all() method to only certain number of results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am creating a webscraper that extracts small business' emails. I am using beautiful soup for scraping. Essentially, the program searches google for a keyword, stores the first 20 links in a list, and for each of these links, it parses it using beautiful soup, searches for all the href attributes that contain the word "contact", goes on these contact pages and extracts the emails.

Now,  I only want to extract information in small business websites. Here comes the problem: sometimes, there will be a link to a huge website like alibaba or amazon which I don't want, since the search time will be way too long. I tried making a blacklist for them, but there's is still a possiblity that I encounter a huge website that I did not know of.

Is there a way we can limit the beautiful soup find_all() method for the following segment of code:

```
menu = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

Here, menu is a list of links found on the main page. Then, for these links, I store only the ones that has contact in them (ignoring case), like so:

```
for item in menu:
          if contains("Contact", str(item)):
             filtered_menu.append(item)
```

Here, contains is a method that I defined.

So, can we limit the find_all() method?
Another approach that comes to my mind is maybe limiting the for loop that searches for contact. How would you do this in this case?

Here is my contains method:

```
def contains(substring, string):
     if substring.lower() in string.lower():
          return True
     else:
          return False
```

Comment: What is your `contains` method... you can probably use that within `.find_all()`... (eg: is it looking for `Contact` anywhere in anything or the href or the immediate text of the link or...)

Comment: its nothing much, it just compares ignoring case. I will add the code in the question right now. It is looking for contact anywhere in the <a href> attribute. I filter it to just the link later on in the code.

Comment: right... can you please if answer is it "Contact" *anywhere* for that tag... or Contact has to appear in the href or the immediate text of the the anchor or anywhere in siblings or... ?

Comment: contact anywhere in the tag, I have another filter after this later on in the code that checks the immediate text after the href

Comment: including siblings or... ?

Comment: yes including siblings

Comment: Maybe try starting with... `soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.has_attr('href') and 'Contact' in str(tag))` ?

Comment: Alright i'll try this, but does it ignore cases for Contact? Also, does it strictly search for ''Contact" or can it include "Contact Us" or similar things

Comment: depends what you want... maybe make it `'contact' in str(tag).lower()` ?

Answer (score 1):

[You can pass in a number for `limit`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument):

```py
find_all("h3", limit=10) # only 10 h3 elements will be extracted
```

Method signature: [`find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

---

P.S. There's a [dedicated web scraping blog](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine. If you need to parse search engines, have a try using [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.